# Some kind of a generative loop

Tags: c++, templates

I have this piece of code:

```
template<class T, class color_type>
void assign_channels(T* ptr, const color_type& color) {
    *(ptr + 0) = get_channel<0>(color);

    if constexpr(1 < color_type::size) {
        *(ptr + 1) = get_channel<1>(color);
    }
    if constexpr(2 < color_type::size) {
        *(ptr + 2) = get_channel<2>(color);
    }
    if constexpr(3 < color_type::size) {
        *(ptr + 3) = get_channel<3>(color);
    }
    if constexpr(4 < color_type::size) {
        *(ptr + 4) = get_channel<4>(color);
    }
    if constexpr(5 < color_type::size) {
        *(ptr + 5) = get_channel<5>(color);
    }
    if constexpr(6 < color_type::size) {
        *(ptr + 6) = get_channel<6>(color);
    }
    if constexpr(7 < color_type::size) {
        *(ptr + 7) = get_channel<7>(color);
    }
}
```

It has two clear flaws:

1. It won't work properly unless I have no more than 8 channels;
2. It's mostly boilerplate.

Is there a way in C++ to rewrite it in some kind of a loop? I think a recurring templated struct would do the job, but it's not really readable. What should I do?

Comment: Why is `get_channel` a template? o.0'

Comment: @Alexander It's a long story of a really flexible `color_t` with minimized run–time overhead. :|

Comment: The more common way of expressing `*(ptr + 5)` is `ptr[5]`.

Comment: And the name of that function sucked too, I didn't want to waste my time on refactoring stuff that I had to rewrite anyway. Now there is no ugly pointer arithmetic and the name's nice too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use fold expressions and `std::index_sequence` in C++17

```
template<class T, class color_type, size_t... Is>
void assign_channels(T* ptr, const color_type& color, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    ((ptr[Is] = get_channel<Is>(color)), ...);
}

template<class T, class color_type>
void assign_channels(T* ptr, const color_type& color) {
    assign_channels(ptr, color, std::make_index_sequence<color_type::size>{});
}
```

Prior to C++17, you'd have to rewrite the fold expression as recursion.